Why doesn't IntelliSense work properly when I create console application in Visual Studio?
Problem description:
The problem appears when I'm trying to create a console application through terminal in folder using dotnet new console or dotnet new console --use-program-main commands(I've tried only these two).
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.10.5**
SDK version: 8.0.303**
Nothing custom wasn't installed just packages I need
I know that I can create console application through built-in function, but I was using VS Code for a while, that's why I decided to repeat the creation pattern from there.
On the screenshot I missed register, but there aren't any red squiggles to recall me that I made a mistake 
Packages I've installed: ASP.NET, Azure, classic .NET aplications, data storage and processing.
My .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

What have I tried:
Mostly that was something plain like reloading and reinstalling(so I assume that everything booted properly)

Try creating a solution file (dotnet new sln), add the project to the solution (dotnet sln add project.csproj), and then open the solution file in VS

@Mathias R. Jessen, that worked, thank you so much!

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78271636/10024425

As you have followed the method provided by @Mathias R. Jessen, the problem has now been solved. However, I would like to share a few suggestions about this problem. If you encounter similar problems with IntelliSense later, you can try to follow them to troubleshoot.
1.First of all, please confirm whether you have enabled the option "Show error squiggles” by going to Tools > Options > Text Editor > General. If not, please enable it.
2.Please check whether you have installed some third-party extensions like ReSharper. Sometimes it could affect visual studio native IntelliSense such as "Hide all visual studio squiggles". If so, please try to disable it.
3.Run command devenv /ResetSettings at Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 to restore visual studio default settings.
4 Try to delete .vs folder in your project and then reload your project to see if squiggles reappear.
